# Autorefreshing included table, need to retrieve selected row's cell value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an auto-refreshing table (works) that is pulled from MySQL to keep info updated within the last 10 seconds. That table is in an included php file, so I can use .load() to call it for refreshing.

Using help I found on the internet, I was able to successfully make a jquery script that highlights and selects the row you click on. It worked when the table was static, but no longer now that it's dynamic (being auto refreshed).

Knowing very little about JQuery, how can I preserve the value of the row that was clicked on AKA it holds onto that number, so when the user clicks "Confirm Selection", that number is passed through the form for submission.

For example;
While viewing the list, I see two entires: "0008" and "0009". I click on "0008", the table refreshes, and 0008 may or may not still be on the list. However, when I clicked on it, it preserved "0008", so when I click "Confirm Selection", the value "0008" is passed.

As of right now, the alert just pops up and says, "undefined".
(I should probably add, I also tried .text() instead of .html())

```
<script src="java/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function refreshInfoBox() {
    $('#infobox').load('refreshtable.php');
    setTimeout(refreshInfoBox, 10000);
}
setTimeout(refreshInfoBox, 10000);

$(document).ready(function() {

    refreshInfoBox();

    $("#tableinfo tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
        var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
        });

        $('.select').on('click', function(e){
            alert($("#tableinfo tr.selected td:first").html());
    });
});

</script>
<div id="fixed">

    <?php
        include("topmenu.php");
    ?>

    <div id="backpanel">
        <div id="infobox">
            <?php
                include("refreshtable.php");
            ?>
        </div>
    <input type="button" name="OK" class="select" value="Confirm Selection"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

**refreshtable.php**

```
<table id ="tableinfo">
<tr><th width="12%">ID#</th>
<th width="8%">HEADER2</th>
<th width="40%">HEADER3</th>
<th width="40%">HEADER4</th>
</tr>

$query= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbtable ORDER BY dbtime");
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowCount();
if($count > 0)
{
    while($info = $query->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $info['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['field2']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['field3']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['field4']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?
    }
}?></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery here `$("#tableinfo tr").click(function(){` binds to a DOM element within your page. Not any DOM element with that id but an explicit instance of that element, the one which exists at that time.

When your refresh script runs the table is replaced with a new table. It may have the same ID as the old table, but it's not the table your function was bound to so your function can't reference it.

You could rebind the function to the new table each time, but a better way to do this would be to only fetch the data you actualy need.

Instead of reloading the whole table you could poll the server for updates, return them as minimal JSON and insert them as new rows into the table using the success function of your ajax call. There would be less data overhead and it would be a better user experience.

Given you know very little about jQuery that may not make much sense just yet. Have a look at the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function as a starting point.

Comment: The problem with this, if I understand the idea, is that while adding new rows is good for new entries to the database, if an old entry is deleted and no longer available, I would need it to disappear from the table, which is why it updates the way it does. I could try leaving <table> outside the refresh, that way only the rows/cells are being changed.

Comment: And that's a no go. Just created even more issues. Going back to the old way. How would I rebind the function? As long as I can get it to work now, I can do cool tricks/optimization before releasing it to my group.